# Enter to Tab script does not pass over a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to convert enter into tab, and it works perfect with my form fields, but not a checkbox on my page.  Anyone have any ideas as to why not?

Enter to Tab code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tabE(obj, e) {
  var e = (typeof event != 'undefined') ? window.event : e; // IE : Moz

  var self = $(obj),
    form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
    focusable, next;

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(obj) + 1);
    if (!next.length) {
      next = focusable.first();
    }
    next.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

The Evil Checkbox :

```
<input class="case" type="checkbox" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);"/>
```

Edit: (HTML Code) :

```
<td> <input class="case" type="checkbox" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);"/> </td>
```

jquery :

```
 html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_'+i+'" type="checkbox"/></td>';
```

Comment: How is `tabE` being called?

Comment: That seems like a horrible user experience.

Comment: @swa66 funny that you should say that, it was actually a feature that was requested :P

Comment: Show them the tab key: the rest of the Internet works that way too. In fact their browser is designed to do that and it's one of the few things most mainstream browsers actually agree on.

Comment: @swa66 ...Reasons why clients can suck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Now updated to show it continues to work if the checkboxes are created dynamically.

```js
function tabE(obj, e) {
  var e = (typeof event != 'undefined') ? window.event : e; // IE : Moz

  var self = $(obj),
      form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'),
      focusable, next;

  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
    next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(obj) + 1);
    if (!next.length) {
      next = focusable.first();
    }
    next.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
var lId = 0;
$(function () {
  $('#addNewCheck').on('click', function(e) {
    lId +=1;
    $('<input id="' + lId + '" class="case" type="checkbox" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);"/>').insertAfter(':checkbox:last');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<form action="action_page.php">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);"><br><br>
    Case:<br>
    <input class="case" type="checkbox" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onkeypress="return tabE(this,event);">
</form>
<br>
<button id="addNewCheck">Add new  checkbox </button>
```

Comment: I tested sw in ie chrome and ff. In ff you fo not see the focus but I assure you the SW works. Indeed I wrote this snippet.  Thanks so much

Comment: In my snippet I use key press instead of key up

Comment: I will give it a try once I get back to the office- Thanks!

Comment: Its still not working on my end, but is on your snippet - SO do you know of any way to check issues with an object within your code?

Comment: I think I founnd the issue, but unsure how to fix it.  The code finds focusable elements in the page whenever you load the page.  The checkbox that is not being able to be skipped over is loaded from a script that adds a line to my form, with a checkbox(case) and several input areas.  Is there a way to allow the script to dynamically detect the added fields?

Comment: I added the relevant code(not much to it) to my answer.  Is there anything you are looking for specifically?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the fact that the checkbox is added dynamically within the page- does your code take that in account?

Comment: It continues to works. I updated the snippet, so you can take a look

Comment: If a field does not contain the onkeypress this is a mistake, so please take a look on how I create a new checkbox and the all input field with the onkeypress event.  Let me know if you continue to have problem. If you want can you upvote?

Comment: I have no clue what is going on, lol.  I solved this issue by changing "onkeypress" to "onkeyup" and it works perfect :P

Comment: I'm happy to hear it's going well for you.